# Reached max size for compiled sql statement cache for database problem related to query?

Tags: android, sqlite

friends,

i have written following sqlite insert statement which seems to be wrong.
before inserting row i am checking if record exists then dont insert(ATM data is more than 600 records)

**Reached max size for compiled sql statement cache for database.no space for this sql statement in cache.select 1 from atm where atmid=251 please change your sql statment to use "?" for bindargs, instead of**

```
public void addAtm(ATM atm)
    {

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + AtmsTable.NAME + 
        "(" +AtmsTable.COL_ID + ","
        +AtmsTable.COL_BankID +"," 
        + AtmsTable.COL_BankNAME+","
        + AtmsTable.COL_BankPhone+","
        + AtmsTable.COL_BankAddress+","
        + AtmsTable.COL_BankCoordinates+","
        + AtmsTable.COL_BankCity+","
        + AtmsTable.COL_BankWebaddress+") Values (" 
        +atm.getAtmID()+","
        +atm.getBankID()
        + ",'" + atm.getBankName().trim()
        +"','" + atm.getPhone()
        +"','" + atm.getAddress()
        +"','" + atm.getCoordinates()
        +"','" + atm.getCity()
        +"','" + atm.getWebAddress()+ "');");

}
```

and

```
public boolean atmExists(int atmId)
    {
        OpenIfNotOpened();
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select 1 from " + AtmsTable.NAME  +" where " + AtmsTable.COL_ID + "=" + atmId,null);
               boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
               cursor.close();
               return exists;
    }
```

and i am getting following error message

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public void execSQL (String sql)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Execute a single
>   SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or
>   any other SQL statement that returns
>   data. It has no means to return any
>   data (such as the number of affected
>   rows). Instead, you're encouraged to
>   use insert(String, String,
>   ContentValues), update(String,
>   ContentValues, String, String[]), et
>   al, when possible.

just use:

```
ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
vals.put(AtmsTable.COL_BankID, atm.getBankID());
vals.put(AtmsTable.COL_BankNAME, atm.getBankName().trim());
/...
if(db.update(AtmsTable.NAME, vals, AtmsTable.COL_ID + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(atm.getAtmID())}) == 0){
  vals.put(AtmsTable.COL_ID, atm.getAtmID());
  db.insert(AtmsTable.NAME, null, vals);
}
```